# XML Schema validator error on attribute declaration

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I get an error on validation:

Error - Line 14, 36: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 36; s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'simpleType' must match (annotation?, (restriction | list | union)). A problem was found starting at: attribute.

How to resolve it?

My XML fragment

```
<CHANEL_NAME lang="RUS/MD">N4</CHANEL_NAME>
```

And XSD:

```
<xs:element name="CHANEL_NAME">
    <xs:simpleType>
         <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="40"/>
        </xs:restriction>
        <xs:attribute name="lang">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="MD"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RUS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="RUS/MD"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

So I need in attribute 'lang' only determined values like 'MD', 'RUS' or 'RUS/MD'. I read examples and I guess it's OK.

Or is enumeration only for elements and not for attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the first `simpleType`. Simple types can't have attribute.

You probably need a complex type with simple content. Something like:

```
<xs:element name="CHANEL_NAME">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:length value="40"/>
       <xs:attribute name="lang">
         <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
             <xs:enumeration value="MD"/>
             <xs:enumeration value="RUS"/>
             <xs:enumeration value="RUS/MD"/>
           </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
       </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

(Not tested.)

Also consider naming your anonymous types.

ps. Also consider using/restricting `xs:language` as language type.

Всего наилучшего.